# How to launch groovy console during runtime of a java program

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I want to launch groovy console during runtime of my java program and Groovy Console should be able to access some java variables
ex.

```
int x = 5 ;// a variable in java program   
launchGroovyConsole(); // hypothetical method to launch groovy console
```

Now in groovy console x should be accessible

```
println x  
==> 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just summarizing here how we can launch Groovy Console in run time.
We can include below code in  java class or in groovy  class to launch groovy console.

```
import groovy.ui.Console
public class TestGroovyConsole{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 5;
        Console console = new Console();
        console.setVariable("x",x);// to make x available in console
        console.run(); // to launch console
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `/bin` folder of your groovy installation. There you'll find the `GroovyConsole.bat` script in which you'll find a reference to `groovy.ui.Console`: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/ui/Console.html

This contains the `main()` method of the console - you should be able to launch it though this method.

Regarding the *binding* of variables to the console, I guess the documentation link above will help you to figure out how to make your local variables accessible from within the console.